# How to prove from the axioms of real numbers that for every real number there is both a greater and a lesser real number?

Tags: real-analysis

This is something that I have seen no real analysis book prove, and I have read quite a few. How does one prove that for every real number $x$, there are real numbers $y$ and $z$ such that $z < x < y$? I want to prove it from the complete ordered field axioms. I know it is true, I just want to see a rigorous proof.

Comment: Just define $y = x - 1$ and $z = x + 1$. It should be very straightforward to prove $y < x < z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The defining properties of an ordered field (whether the real numbers or any other) are that the order is preserved under addition of any element to both sides (i.e., if $y<z$, then $x+y<x+z$) (Rudin, Def. 1.17 i) and that two positive numbers have a product that is also positive (i.e., if $x>0$, $y>0$, then $x\cdot y >0$) (Def. 1.17 ii).

From these remarkably simple two axioms, in combination with the field axioms, we generate all of the usual principles of inequalities in the real numbers. See Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* p. 7, Def. 1.17. One almost immediate consequence of these axioms is that $1>0$ (Rudin, Prop. 1.18 d).

This immediately provides an example affirming your claim, using just Def. 1.17 i, Prop. 1.18 d, and the field axioms:

$$1>0\Rightarrow x+1>x+0
\\
1>0\Rightarrow 0>-1 \Rightarrow 0+x>-1+x
\\
\Rightarrow x-1 < x < x+1$$

Answer (score 1):

The two numbers $z=x-1$ and $y=x+1$ exist, and it is not difficult to see by the axioms of ordered fields that they fulfill your inequality.